# Using GitHub and Eclipse to pull code

Tags: eclipse, git, github

I have a repo [on GitHub here](https://github.com/the1mills/db4oProject).

I have pushed to this repo from two different machines, so now one machine is current and another has outdated code. Right now, I am on the machine with outdated code, and I want to pull in the master/HEAD/whatever from GitHub.

And then I get to stare at this:

[image]

I do not want to do something stupid like delete the project from Eclipse and then pull in all the code from GitHub.

Can someone please help me merge/synchronize the projects? This is as simple as it sounds.

Unfortunately, this is what happens when I click "Pull" on the above menu:

[image]

Would someone also explain what the difference is between Pull, Merge, Fetch and Synchronize?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

eGit doesn't know, which remote branch you want to pull from. 
If you create your local branch based on a remote tracking branch, then the key is generated automatically. Otherwise you have to create it yourself:

```
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
branch.master.remote=origin
```

where master stands for the `branchname`, in the key it's your local branch, in the value it's the branch in the remote repository. Place that in the repository-specific configuration file `%repositorypath%\.git\config`

As for the terms:

- `merge`: join two or more development histories together
- `fetch`: download objects and refs from another repository
- `pull`: fetch from and merge with another repository or local branch
- `sync`: allows you to compare 2 branches

**In general, I urge you to read eGit user guide, where you can get even better understanding of Git and eGit. It can be found at http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide**